# Usage of ID tokens and Access tokens, with external Authentication, AWS backend and graphql language

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, graphql, authorization

I am currently working on building a mobile app which will require the users be authenticated, and have them specific privileges on what they can do (for example, a logged in user will only be able to manage some of their data held in the backend database).

I think I do understand the differences between ID token (user identity) and Access token (for authorizing between the mobile phone client and the back-end), but I am not sure what I intend to do conforms to the best practices regarding authentication and authorization.

Let me summarize what I am planning to do:

- front end will be a Flutter/Dart mobile app
- authentication will be done through Google Firebase Authentication service
- my back end will be hosted in AWS:

  - API Gateway will serve a unique graphQL endpoint
  - API Gateway has an associated Lambda authorizer function which processes requests prior to the actual "application" Lambda functions
  - "application" Lambda function serves GraphQL requests (using python ariadne library), including authorization business logic
  - Database is a managed PostGreSQL inside AWS

The authentication / authorization workflow is as follow:

[image]

Not all of this has been implemented yet, but on the paper I think it could work.

However, it goes against several good practices regarding token usage:

- the ID token is sent along an API call which is advised against (see [this nice auth0 blog post](https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/))
- I make no usage of access token between the front end and the back-end (could the AWS policy generated at step 5 fullfill this role?)
- I do not leverage the audience claims in tokens

**Note:** as GraphQL exposes a single endpoint, I am not sure of what the content of the access token should be

I am new to Authentication / Authorization and would gladly have some insight regarding the best way to actually make everything work as per best practices, accounting to the following contraints:

- authentication is outside of AWS
- the APIs are GraphQL

Comment: Is there any reason why you have the front talk directly to firebase instead of going through your backend and having it talk to fb? Would make managing secrets easier and also keep your front simpler. Also with your archi you have to sync your user db with firebase. Just seems like you have extra complexity here relative to the usual GraphQL auth pattern. What benefits are you getting from that extra complexity?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Michel. I totally am ready to review this architecture schema, and have no issue challenging it. I don't think I am getting any benefit from linking the front directly to FB. What would the usual GraphQL auth pattern you mention look like? Should I send user credentials (email + password) from the front to the back directly? In which part of my architecture would I then call FB for authentication (lambda authorizer ?) ?

Comment: I recently posted about auth, you could see one pattern here: https://michelfloyd.hashnode.dev/jwt-authentication-in-apollo-v4-part-1. But yes, the lambda authorizer seems like the place to handle both the issuing and validation of tokens. It can in turn interact with FB or other potential auth providers.